# Android Jpg + png images display as white color

Tags: android, kotlin, androidx

Some of my resource images display as white color and I have no idea why. 
 - I'm using a drawable importer plugin to import my images in multiple densities. 
 - Image displays if I set it as Background resource but then I can't control it's dimensions:

- used `src`, `compatSrc` attributes and nothing changes.
- tried to load the image using `glide` and nothing changes.

xml

> ```
>    <ImageView
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="320dp"
>     android:scaleType="centerCrop"
>     android:src="@drawable/graphic_map"/>
> ```

[Expmple png image Layout in xml preview vs in emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/civsP.png)

[Example jpg Image Location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kRqlK.png)

Comment: Can you post an example image, the location in your project of said image and the code you tried (xml or java) to include the image?

Comment: @JensV edited..

Comment: Does the preview actually not match the actual image or did you take the screenshot with another image included? This does indeed seem very weird and I've never seen that before. If possible could you upload the image itself somewhere so we can test it?

Comment: Also check all dpi versions of your image, possibly your importer plugin messed up the different resolutions?

Comment: It is weird indeed. That's the actual image from the preview, I've also tried to place different images in the drawable folder without using the Importer but I still got the same results.